# Purpose of a GD-Zn alloy

Tags: materials, automotive-engineering, metallurgy, alloys

Here are screenshots of the data-sheets of two separate products for a reference. They both are nickel plated, used for coupling nuts. The [former](https://www.turck.de/datasheet/_en/edb_6932999_gbr_en.pdf) is shielded, the [latter](https://www.turck.de/datasheet/_en/edb_6626491_gbr_en.pdf) is not, I wonder if this is the main reason to chose one over the other.

GD-Zn coupling nut:

[image: GD-Zn product]

CuZn coupling nut:

[image: CuZn product]

I believe GD stands for Gadolinium (Gd), but I might be wrong. I could not find much on the internet, apart from the [following](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/0-306-47090-X_75):

> Alloying Gd with Zn significantly reduces melting temperature of the alloys (the eutectic alloy melts at ∼860°C) compared to that of pure Gd (1313°C) and also improves the ductility over the GdZn intermetallide.

This information however is about comparing Gadolinium Zinc alloy with pure Gadolinium, not pure Zinc. It hints us about the manufacturing process of such an alloy, and I suspect it has more to do with itch electro-magnetic properties, which are unclear to me.

What is the purpose of GD-Zn alloy? What advantages they provide over CuZn (Brass) alloy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I look on the net I found a surprising result : GD seems to stand for German Din (material specifications). GD Zinc is a zinc die cast alloy with 4 Cu and 1 Al. Equivalent to AG 41A alloy in the US. So one of the components is brass ,the other is an ( ordinary) zinc die cast.